# Configure iptables to drop established connections whenever rules change

Tags: linux, iptables

I am using iptables on Debian jessie (Linux kernel 3.16). If I make a change to the iptables rule file and then use `iptables-restore` to reload iptables making it aware of the changes, any connections that were established *before* the reload are maintained, even if they would be prevented by the new rules.

How can I configure iptables, or reload the rules, so that these established connections are dropped if they no longer meet the new rules that are being loaded?

**Example**: Before the change, all connections to port 80 are blocked, except from address 192.168.0.100. I want to change this so that only connections from address 192.168.0.200 to port 80 are allowed. So, I edit our text file of iptables rules and change the rule. Before I run the `iptables-restore` command I notice that there is currently a connection to port 80 from 192.168.0.100. I reload the rules. What I want to happen is for the established connection from 192.168.0.100 to be automatically dropped since it no longer is allowed under the new rules.

Comment: I think you could run `iptables -F` to flush all rules, then reload the rules file.

Comment: The right tool for this is [conntrack](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/conntrack/conntrack.8.en.html). You can ask it to display the flows (including those only from 192.168.0.100) and likewise to delete them from netfilter's conntrack entries. You still have to use some elbow grease to figure out what to delete (or you can flush all). Check also the role of [nf_conntrack_tcp_loose](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/nf_conntrack-sysctl.txt?h=v4.16#n106)